# "Power and battery" option does not open in settings

Tags: windows, power-options

In settings > system, every tab works, but the power and battery tabs do not work. When I try to go into power and battery settings the settings window closes

windows version: WINDOWS 11 23H2 OS BUILD 22631.2792

[video](https://streamable.com/fr8woh)

Comment: Can you please show a screen shot instead of a video. Thank you.  Try updating the Power Driver.  Also see if the manufacturer offers its own tool. Lenovo offers Vantage, for example.

Comment: You fail to identify which version of Windows you are using

Comment: @John When I press the power and battery, the window closes. How can I explain this with a screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound The problem has been going on for a while. I am currently using Windows 11 23H2, but the problem was also in 22H2.

current version: WINDOWS 11 23H2 OS BUILD 22631.2792

Comment: Try also running DISM / SFC.      (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.   If that fails, you will need to try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Comment: What is your computer model ?

Comment: @John 

sfc /scannow result: Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup result: The operation completed successfully.


DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth result: The operation completed successfully.

I restarted the computer and the problem still persists

Comment: @harrymc OMEN by HP 15-dc1011nt

Comment: Run again `sfc /scannow` and keep on running it as long as it finds things to correct, then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Driver updates and DISM  did not fix the issue.

So then:

**(1) Run a Windows 11 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.  The default Keep prompt is to Keep
> Everything.

A Repair Install with Keep Everything retains Apps and Data.

**(2) If Windows 11 Repair fails to fix the issue:**

Back everything up and do a fresh install of Windows 11

If HP offers good support for it, update BIOS (UEFI) as well

Comment: Will this delete any applications or files on my computer? I don't want anything to be deleted from my computer

Comment: A Repair Install with Keep Everything will NOT delete applications and files. But then if that does not fix things, you will need to back up an reinstall.